# Uncertainty of a trend

Tags: r, confidence-interval, uncertainty

I need to estimate the confidence interval of the solar radiation change (in %) over time. For this, I'm going to use `R` default dataset `airquality`. Let's imagine that we know that the measurement error of `Solar.R` is 30% (`UME`). Hence, `UME` can be simulated as a random number from a normal distribution with a mean of 1 and a standard deviation of 0.30. Therefore I calculate 95% confidence intervals on the solar radiation as the difference between the 97.5% and 2.5% quantile of the 1000 simulated values.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Load dataset and keep only June
df <- airquality %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  filter(Month == 6) %>% 
  dplyr::select(day = Day,
                solar = Solar.R)

# Create a function to estimate uncertainties
unc <- function(x){
  
  ume <- rnorm(1000,
               mean = 1,
               sd = .3)
  
  sim <- x * ume
  
  quantile(sim, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    rename(val = 2) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rowname,
                values_from = val) %>% 
    rename(lower = 1,
           upper = 2)
  
}

# Calculate CI attributed to measuring errors
set.seed(2021)
df_sim <- df %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(sim = map(data, ~unc(.x$solar))) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(data, sim)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Plot
df_sim %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day,
             y = solar)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower,
                  ymax = upper),
              alpha = .4) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              se = F)
```

[image]

So there is obviously a negative trend. The main question is, *how can I calculate a slope and corresponding slope's CI considering the **measurement uncertainty** of `Solar.R`*? I end up with two various solutions. Help me to select the right, please. Or suggest another, more robust way.

#### Way 1

From googling ([here](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys311/workshops/w2c/slope_uncert.html) and [here](https://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/rallain/plab193/page1/page35/page36/page36.html)), I found that I can get the difference between the lower value at the beginning and the upper in the end, and vice versa. E.g.

```
df_sim %>% 
  summarize(
    average = mean(solar),
    slope_lower = (first(lower) - last(upper))/30,
    slope_upper = (last(lower) - first(upper))/30
         ) %>% 
  mutate(change_lower = slope_lower / average * 100,
         change_upper = slope_upper / average * 100)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   average slope_lower slope_upper change_lower change_upper
#>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1    190.       -3.12       -13.3        -1.64        -6.98
```

So, from these calculations, I can see that my CI is [-1.64%; -6.98%].

#### Way 2

Calculate 3 slopes: for original `Solar.R`, for its upper and lower values. E.g.

```
df_sim %>% 
  gather(var, val, -day) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(mod = map(data,
                   ~lm(val ~ day,
                       data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(average = map_dbl(data, ~mean(.x$val))) %>% 
  mutate(slope = map_dbl(mod, ~(.x$coefficients[2]))) %>% 
  # Calculate change in %
  mutate(change = slope / 190 * 100) # 190 is an average
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Groups:   var [3]
#>   var   data                  mod    average  slope change
#>   <chr> <list>                <list>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 solar <tibble[,2] [30 x 2]> <lm>     190.   -6.85  -3.61
#> 2 lower <tibble[,2] [30 x 2]> <lm>      78.5  -2.88  -1.52
#> 3 upper <tibble[,2] [30 x 2]> <lm>     303.  -11.1   -5.83
```

Using this approach, my CI is [-1.52%; -5.83%].

Comment: You could try a bootstrap. Where for each bootstrap iteration you simulate individual datapoints, fit a model to get regression coefficients. Then if you do this a number of times, you can use the distribution of regression coefficients to approximate the uncertainty of the intercept/trend.